# Mostrar alumnos asignados a un grupo JAVA

Tags: java, poo

que necesito hacer para mostrar una lista de alumnos asignados a un grupo?

[image: asigne en la linea 10]

Comment: Hey user63369, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: ¿Donde creas la lista de alumnos?

Comment: En mi main principal

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Alumno genA[]=new Alumno[20];

Comment: Al preguntar debes ser especifico, agrega la información necesaria para determinar el problema en tu pregunta, revisa los links que te proporciono, esto para que no sea cerrada tu pregunta o con puntuación negativa. :(

Comment: Deja reformular mi pregunta con la guia,

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información

Comment: Además, procura poner el código en tu pregunta como texto, no como imagen.

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo el codigo que necesitas:

```
public class Persona {

private String nombre;

public Persona(){}

public Persona(String nombre){
    this.nombre=nombre;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

}

```
public class Grupo {

private String idGrupo;
private String nombreGrupo;

public Grupo(){}

public Grupo(String idGrupo,String nombreGrupo){
    this.idGrupo=idGrupo;
    this.nombreGrupo=nombreGrupo;
}

public String getIdGrupo() {
    return idGrupo;
}

public void setIdGrupo(String idGrupo) {
    this.idGrupo = idGrupo;
}

public String getNombreGrupo() {
    return nombreGrupo;
}

public void setNombreGrupo(String nombreGrupo) {
    this.nombreGrupo = nombreGrupo;
}
```

}

import java.util.List;

public class Alumno extends Persona {

```
public Alumno(String nombre){
    super(nombre);
}

private List<Grupo> ltsGrupos;

public List<Grupo> getLtsGrupos() {
    return ltsGrupos;
}

public void setLtsGrupos(List<Grupo> ltsGrupos) {
    this.ltsGrupos = ltsGrupos;
}
```

}

```
    import java.util.List;

public class ListaAlumnos {

private List<Alumno> lstAlumnos;

public ListaAlumnos(){

}
public ListaAlumnos(List<Alumno> lstAlumnos){
    this.lstAlumnos=lstAlumnos;
}

public List<Alumno> getLstAlumnos() {
    return lstAlumnos;
}

public void setLstAlumnos(List<Alumno> lstAlumnos) {
    this.lstAlumnos = lstAlumnos;
}
```

}

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestAlumno {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Alumno alumno1 = new Alumno("Hugo");
    Alumno alumno2 = new Alumno("Tu nombre");

    Grupo grupo1= new Grupo("1212","Matematicas");
    Grupo grupo2= new Grupo("2222","Programacion");

    List<Grupo> lstGrupo1= new ArrayList<Grupo>();
    lstGrupo1.add(grupo1);
    lstGrupo1.add(grupo2);

    alumno1.setLtsGrupos(lstGrupo1);
    alumno2.setLtsGrupos(lstGrupo1);

    List<Alumno> lstAlumnos = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
    lstAlumnos.add(alumno1);
    lstAlumnos.add(alumno2);

    ListaAlumnos listaAlumnos = new ListaAlumnos(lstAlumnos);

    System.out.println(":::::Lista de Alumnos y sus respectivos grupos:::::::");
    for(Alumno alumno :listaAlumnos.getLstAlumnos() ){
        System.out.println("Nombre: " + alumno.getNombre());
        for(Grupo grupo:alumno.getLtsGrupos()){
            System.out.println("Grupo: " + grupo.getIdGrupo() +"-" +grupo.getNombreGrupo());
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
    }


    }

}
```

Saludos

Comment: No es por ser negativo, pero no deberías contestar una pregunta con todo el código que crees que necesita el OP. Si no queremos que este sitio se vuelva como SO en inglés, en donde las personas piden que les resuelvan sus tareas, deberíamos ser más concretos en ayudar a solucionar problemas y no en resolverles los problemas por ellos.

Comment: Hola, es dificil entender quien tiene razon,  yo aprecio tus comentarios y de ningun modo quise realizar su trabajo de la persona que pregunto, de buen corazon trate de ayudar. Respeto tu opinion pero tambien el tratar de ayudar con algo de codigo no es malo. Yo vi que la pregunta tenia algo de codigo y por eso trate de ayudar. Saludos